# How to change a cookie name with mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, cookies

I'm trying to change the name of a cookie that's set by an AWS ELB, but keep its value with a rewrite condition and rewrite rule.

Here's what I've managed so far:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} AWSELB=(^BD.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [CO=SIMELB:%1:.amazonaws.com:lifetime:-1]
```

Obviously the `RewriteRule` is incorrect, but could someone help me with the right syntax?

Comment: The problem I'm facing is I'm proxied through one AWSELB and going to an application that's also behind an AWSELB. Amazon sets a cookie for each ELB you go to and it messes with session stickiness in my HA environment.

Comment: What is a sample value for the AWSELB cookie? Your only problem may be the () group.

Comment: It's AWSELB=BD1F69170269E014..... (really long value)

Comment: And it always starts with `BD`, or can be anything?

Comment: Yes, it always starts with BD... I'm pretty sure the entire value stays the same, but for ease used regex to match based off of only a couple of characters

Comment: And must you explicitly _unset_ the AWSELB cookie, or just set your custom SIMELB cookie? (it's a lot more complicated to unset the old one)

Comment: I'd like to unset it because when going back to that particular AWSELB, it just sets it again upon entry.

Comment: Last question: what's the domain set for the original `AWSELB` cookie? Is it the same `.amazonaws.com` or something more specific? (more specific will be problematic)

Comment: I believe the .amazonaws.com will work (and it is the domain for moth AWSELB cookies that get set in my scenario), but won't really know for sure until I test. I had a hunch that matching the value would be more important.

Comment: @PO5TMAN Finally got an answer posted. The site went into read-only mode halfway through....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, following the comment thread, I think there's enough info to get started. Foremost, your
pattern doesn't work because of the `(^BD.*)` capture group, and in particular because of
the `^` anchor. Instead, capture `(BD[^;]+)` to grab everything up to the next `;` (or the
end of the string if there isn't one).

To explicitly unset the previous cookie, other examples use the `INVALID` modifier, though I
cannot find the documentation for it.

[Apache mod_rewrite documentation on
Cookies](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_co)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} AWSELB=(BD[^&]+) [NC]
# Delete the old one
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=AWSELM:INVALID:.amazonaws.com:0:/:-1]
# Add the new one
# Specify your lifetime in minutes or 0 for the browser session (60 below)...
# ALso add the path
# Assumimg the -1 is for insecure cookies
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=SIMELB:%1:.amazonaws.com:60:/:-1]
```

For the old cookie to be successfully unset, both the domain and the path will need to
exactly match those originally set by AWS. Inspect the cookies currently being set and make
sure you match the domain & path.

And really, it isn't necessary to match `BD`... You could just as well do `AWSELB=([^;]+)` because it must only match up to the following semicolon anyway.

#### Addendum:

If the value is being lost, it may be because the the `RewriteCond` is only applied to the first subsequent matching `RewriteRule`.  You can always just repeat the `RewriteCond`. This is ugly, unfortunately, but I tested it and found it to work correctly.

```
# no capture group the first time since you don't use it until later
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} AWSELB=BD.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=AWSELM:INVALID:.amazonaws.com:0:/:-1]
# This will continue to execute since the previous didn't have [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} AWSELB=(BD[^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=SIMELB:%1:.amazonaws.com:60:/:-1]
```

(Note: you won't see the cookie value updated until a subsequent HTTP request; that is, if you tried to inspect it from your script right after setting it with Apache, the new value won't be present because the cookie header has to make a round trip back to the client)

Comment: This worked beautifully. Thank you also for the explanations, I'm really trying hard to learn mod_rewrite syntax, but it is difficult; this gave me a nudge in the right direction. Cheers to you

Comment: I did notice though that even though this does unset and change the cookie name, the value is not kept. I'm going to keep researching and see what I can learn and apply.

Comment: @P05TMAN See addendum above for a possible solution to the loss of the cookie value.

Comment: After seeing what was actually going on with mod_dumpio, I used a different approach. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to rewrite the cookie name, I tested with mod_header directives and seem to have addressed my issue with Amazon's ELB cookie breaking session affinity with another Amazon ELB.

```
RequestHeader edit Cookie AWSELB SIMELB
RequestHeader edit Cookie APPELB AWSELB
Header always edit Set-Cookie AWSELB APPELB
Header edit Set-Cookie AWSELB APPELB
```

This so far seems to work, relying on the browser to maintain the memory for me because after the retrieving the value of the first AWSELB on request, when I get the set-Cookie response back from the second AWSELB, the browser sees APPELB={value} and recalls the correct request cookie obtained from the first AWSELB.