# Unset Cookies older than a specific date, for www. and non www domain

Tags: php, cookies

I want to unset all cookies on my domain so that a "fresh start" can be forced for all users...

The following bit of code kind of works, but it doesn't unset cookies from the domain with via `www.`

```
<?
// Check if this script has run before
if (!isset($_COOKIE['purged_once'])) {

  // Check for old cookies
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {

    $cookies = explode(";", $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);

    // Iterate and unset all cookies
    foreach ($cookies as $cookie) {

      $fields = explode("=", $cookie);
      $name = trim(fields[0]);

      // unset any cookie for the current path
      setcookie($name, "", time() - 3600);

      // unset the cookie for the root path
      setcookie($name, "", time() - 3600, "/");
    }
  }

  // Set a purged marker for the current path
  setcookie("purged_once", "1", strtotime("+6 months"));
}
?>
```

The website is forced to use **non-www** and **https** via .htaccess rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Force HTTPS & NON-WWW
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on  [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^website\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://website.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

So what I am looking for is a way to run this over the `https://www.website.com` to forcefully remove all cookies for that *subdomain*

How can this be achieved?

Comment: why you at all need to modify `www` domain cookies if you have force redirect in your `.htaccess` and your website is always used as `non-www`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `setcookie` function also accepts domain name as a parameter. When you have set no domain name, you create cookie only for current domain. When you have set a domain name, you create cookie for domain and all its sub-domains. For example, `setcookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value', 3600, '/', 'website.com')` creates cookies for `example.com` and all sub-domains, e.g. `www.example.com`, `sub.example.com`, etc. Some older browsers require a dot before domain name to indicate that you want to set cookie for sub-domain:

```
setcookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value', 3600, '/', '.website.com');
```

So, if you want to have some guarantee while unsetting cookies, you can use both approaches:

```
  // unset any cookie for the current path
  setcookie($name, "", time() - 3600, '', 'website.com');
  setcookie($name, "", time() - 3600, '', '.website.com');

  // unset the cookie for the root path
  setcookie($name, "", time() - 3600, "/", 'website.com');
  setcookie($name, "", time() - 3600, "/", '.website.com');
```

---

Description for `domain` parameter of [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) function:

> ```
> setcookie ($name, $value, $expire, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly)
> ```
>
> **$domain**
>
> The (sub)domain that the cookie is available to. Setting this to a subdomain (such as 'www.example.com') will make the cookie available to that subdomain and all other sub-domains of it (i.e. w2.www.example.com). To make the cookie available to the whole domain (including all subdomains of it), simply set the value to the domain name ('example.com', in this case).
>
> Older browsers still implementing the deprecated "RFC 2109" may require a leading . to match all subdomains.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that browsers [share cookies over subdomains](http://www.phpied.com/www-vs-no-www-and-cookies/) (and http and https). So possibly the solution is to just unset them with having the domain parameter set to `www.website.com`, as cookies can only be overwritten with exactly the same set of parameters.

If that does not solve the problem:

- If the possible cookie names are known and a limited set, you can include rewrite rules in the .htaccess before the redirect to unset them, as described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23504346/5049185)
- To find out which cookies exist on the subdomain, add the content of `%{HTTP_COOKIE}` to your query string and parse it in your script and run your code over that as above. Set the domain parameter of [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

The RewriteRule would therefore be changed to

```
RewriteRule ^ https://website.com%{REQUEST_URI}&www_cookies=%{HTTP_COOKIE} [R=301,L]
```

and the cookies will be accessible via `$_REQUEST['www_cookies']` as a string, which still has to be broken apart, for example using [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `$domain` parameter of `setcookie()` (see [php.net setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php))

However, as far as I know, there is no way find out, what cookies are set on a sub-domain. But you could still run your script above for both domains. 
But then only the cookies present at `website.com` will be purged. If there are other cookies set on `www.website.com`, they'll still exist in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are only readable by the domain that created them, so if the cookie was created at https://www.website.com, it will have to be deleted under the same domain as it was created. This includes sub-domains.

If you are required to delete a cookie from non www something.example.com, but are currently running a page at main domain, you will not be able to.

In order to do this, you need to load the page from www.website.com, or create the cookie under something.example.com so it can be accessable under any subdomain. OR use this:

Response.cookies("mycookie").domain = ".something.com"

...while creating it, AND before you delete it.

..untested - should work.